# Magento 2 How to move shipping methods to a new checkout step between shipping and payment steps

Tags: magento2.2, onestepcheckout

I want to add a new checkout step between shipping and payment steps and move shipping methods displaying under shipping address form to that new step.

How can I do that? Is it possible or not?

Comment: This requires a lot of coding. I can recommend starting here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_step.html and then moving things around from the shipping step template to the template of your new method.

Comment: Also, if you are willing to use a third party extension, I can recommend this: https://github.com/danslo/CleanCheckout It does what you want and a lot of other stuff. It basically allows you to configure a lot of stuff in your checkout without any coding.

Comment: @megha did you move shipping method between shipping & payment ? i am also searching for this.